# How to maintain several versions of a document in a single LaTeX file?

Tags: optional-arguments, versions

I want to maintain several versions of my CV in a single LaTeX file, for example:

- version "period1": from 2014 to 2016
- version "period2": from 2017 to 2019
- version "all": from 2014 to 2019

Until now I've been maintaining separate files for each period, but it's a tedious task. I want everything in a single file, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in a simple way, because my CV has to obey to a very specific structure for evaluation purposes.

I've been trying to use the "optional" packages, but it's not easy to maintain and I'm not able to get the desired output. For example, in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[all]{optional} % change "all" to get a specific period
% options:
%   all = period1 + period2
%   period1 = only activities in period 1
%   period2 = only activities in period 2

% allow enumerate without items inside, otherwise compilation might fail
\makeatletter
\let\@noitemerr\relax
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Curriculum Vitae -- \opt{all}{All}\opt{period1}{Period 1}\opt{period2}{Period 2}}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Activity category A:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \opt{all,period1}{
                \item activity 1
            }

            \opt{all,period2}{
                \item activity 2
                \item activity 3
            }

            \opt{all,period3}{
                % nothing 
            }
        \end{enumerate}


        \item Activity category B:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \opt{all,period1}{
                \item activity 1
                \item activity 2
            }

            \opt{all,period2}{
                % nothing 
            }

            \opt{all,period3}{
                \item activity 3
            }
        \end{enumerate}

        \item Activity category C:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \opt{all,period1}{
                % nothing 
            }

            \opt{all,period2}{
                \item activity 1
                \item activity 2
            }

            \opt{all,period3}{
                \item activity 3
            }
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

the "all" option works well. However, the options "period1" and "period2" might show a "Activity category X" without any item -- which I want to avoid:

Current output for "period2" (from the MWE):

- Activity category A:

  1. activity 2
  2. activity 3
- Activity category B:
- Activity category C:

  1. activity 1
  2. activity 2

The desired output would be, without an empty "Activity category B:":

- Activity category A:

  1. activity 2
  2. activity 3
- Activity category C:

  1. activity 1
  2. activity 2

Is there a way to accomplish this output in a way that's easy to maintain in a large CV with many periods?

Comment: does it work to put the \opt around the enumerate environment instead of around a single \item?

Comment: Why don't you use **version control** software? [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke nested \opt should solve the problem, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler, more elegant solution

Comment: @AndréC by using a version control system I will end up to maintain at least 2 versions at a time (the "all" and the "periodX" versions), which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Miguel OK, your question sounded like you were interested in some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, the following works:

```latex
     ...
     \opt{all,period1,period3}{ % mention all cases here, except "empty" ones
        \item Activity category B:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \opt{all,period1}{ % don't need "all" here
                \item activity 1
                \item activity 2
            }

            \opt{all,period2}{
                % nothing 
            }

            \opt{all,period3}{
                \item activity 3
            }
        \end{enumerate}
     }
     ...
```

Comment: your solution works, so I'm accepting it. Thanks